# How to use existing SSH key stored for Virtual Machine creation in azure using ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I have a created SSH key on Azure cloud. Now I want to create a Virtual Machine using the exiting key to use that public key source. Now I want to do this operation using ARM template. I was trying something like this

> **"osProfile"**: {
> "computerName": "myComputerName",
> "adminUsername": "adminUser",
> "linuxConfiguration": {
> "disablePasswordAuthentication": true,
> "ssh": {
> "publicKeys": [
> {
> "path": "[concat('/home/', 'adminUser', '/.ssh/authorized_keys')]",
> "keyData": "how I get public key for the existing ssh key"
> }
> ]
> }
> }
> }

But I'm not sure how to fetch the public key of the created SSH Key.

Answer (score 2):

First build the resource id for your existing ssh key storage on Azure:

```
"variables": {
    "sshKeyResourceId": "[resourceId(variables('sshKeyRg'), 'Microsoft.Compute/sshPublicKeys', variables('sshKeyName'))]",
}
```

Next extract the ssh "keyData" from this resource:

```
"osProfile": {
    "linuxConfiguration": {
        "disablePasswordAuthentication": true,
            "ssh": {
                "publicKeys": [
                    {
                        "keyData": "[reference(variables('sshKeyResourceId'), '2019-12-01').publicKey]",
                        "path": "[concat('/home/', variables('adminUser'), '/.ssh/authorized_keys')]"
                    }
                ]
             }
         }
     }
}
```

See more detailed example [here](https://github.com/dohughes-msft/sap/tree/master/arm/key)

Answer (score 1):

If you have [generated keys with ssh-keygen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/create-ssh-keys-detailed#generate-keys-with-ssh-keygen) on Azure cloud shell. SSH key pairs are by default kept in the `/home/azureuser/.ssh` directory.

To see your public key by running `cat` as follows:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

[image]

Then copy and paste the contents of the public key file into your Resource Manager template, make sure you don't copy any additional whitespace or introduce additional line breaks.

Read more details steps: [Create and manage SSH keys for authentication to a Linux VM in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/create-ssh-keys-detailed#generate-keys-with-ssh-keygen) and [How to create a Linux virtual machine with Azure Resource Manager templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/create-ssh-secured-vm-from-template?toc=/azure/virtual-machines/linux/toc.json)

Comment: Thanks Nancy for your response, I read about cat command, but thing is from which machine/system should I run `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub command` ? because existing ssh key is available on azure cloud, not in my local system.

Comment: Do you mean Azure cloud shell or others? If it exists on the cloud shell, you can open your cloud shell, then run the command as my screenshot.

Comment: Is the issue fixed on your side?

Comment: not yet fixed, the SSH key exists on azure cloud in my subscription. I want that public key content at run time (while executing my application). it is possible to get that using cloud shell? describe me please.

Comment: Where is your application? Do you also want to deploy arm template that will fetch the ssh key on the Azure cloud shell?

Comment: If your application is on your local system, you could download the SSH public key from the path `/home/azureuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` via clicking the *Upload and Download files* button on the Azure cloud shell.

Comment: yes my application is in local system, and it generates arm template where I need that public key.

Comment: Can you consider downloading the SSH key or generating SSH locally? I think it's easier. SSH key is generated on the Azure cloud, it stored at azure file share. Otherwise, you need access the data from that file share or mount your specific file share. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/persisting-shell-storage#how-cloud-shell-storage-works

Comment: I can download for me only, but If other user wants to run my application, he/she will only bother about keyName not the publicKey data.

Comment: May I know what's the specific application? How clients will need the SSH private key or public key there on Azure cloud shell?

Comment: Its my own Java application where I create virtual machine which generates a ARM template and filled keyData of linuxConfiguration at run time, But I only know SshKey name not the KeyData(which is publicKey)

Comment: Sorry, I still confusing what you are trying to do and does not understand why you generate SSK key pairs in Azure cloud shell. But I think I have answered your original question "how to fetch the public key of the created SSH Key.". If you want to store the Key where other users could fetch it easily, you can store it on Azure storage account or Azure key vault.